# Starting flask with uwsgi

Tags: flask, uwsgi

I have a simple Flask app which I can currently run using the flask development server that's included. However, I'm struggling to get my head around the clean way to run it with uwsgi.

My current set up is below:

```
aircraft 
   app
     __init__.py
   aircraft_tracker.py
   start.wsgi
```

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
import settings


def create_app():
    flask_app = Flask(settings.APP_NAME)
    flask_app.config.from_prefixed_env()

    return flask_app
```

**aircraft_tracker.py**

```
from app import create_app


app = create_app()

@app.route('/aircraft', methods=['GET'])
def get_aircraft():
    """Return a list of all active aircraft"""
    ...
    return aircraft

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

**start.wsgi**

```
import aircraft.app
application = aircraft.app.create_app()
```

**wsgi.ini configuration file**

```
wsgi-file = /aircraft/start.wsgi
```

When I run `python aircraft_tracker.py` it runs and all flask routes are included.

If I run using uwsgi the Flask app is created but none of the routes in `aircraft_tracker` are included which makes sense as this file isn't part of the `start.wsgi` script. However I'm not sure how to do it with the circular requirement for app!?

Comment: Well, you never run() the app within your wsgi it would seem. Can you update which wsgi command you're using to start it?

Comment: It's in the wsgi.ini config file I have `wsgi-file = /aircraft/start.wsgi` which will then run the application.

Comment: The flask app is running, the issue is the routes never get "added" to the flask app as aircraft_tracker.py is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Your (or actually a) flask app is running, because in your `start.wsgi`you import from **aircraft/app/** and then use there create_app() (defined in aircraft/app/**init**.py). Since routes are defined in `aircraft_tracker.py` however, your running app cannot know these.

(Without knowing any more details about how you invoke the wsgi, I can't promise this will work out of the box - )

**start.wsgi** (though I'd be tempted to rename it to *start.py*)

```
from aircraft_tracker import app
```

(And that's it).

*If you don't want to use the routes defined in your `aircraft_tracker.py` then you'd need to define them elsewhere - for instance in app/routes.py*